# Know any tricks for navigating the MySQL CLI?

Tags: bash, mysql

For example, ^e jumps to the beginning, ^e jumps to the end, and ^w deletes the next word. ^l is clear, ^k deletes, ^j enters, ^b goes backwards...

It seems similar to [bash shortcuts](http://www.ice2o.com/bash_quick_ref.html) but still somewhat different.

Comment: I don't use mysql so i can't say for sure but isn't this just emacs editor mode? Does it respect your EDITOR environment variable?

Comment: No. It's similar, but different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ending a query in \e takes you into your editor, which is handy for modifying long, convoluted queries

```
SELECT foo FROM bar\e
```